# Connecting a closed loop in seaborn.lineplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a list of 2d points I can plot in seaborn with a `lineplot`, but I want to connect the last point back to the first.  It seems that simply adding the first point to the end of the DataFrame should be sufficient, but for some reason this does not work.  My current solution is to just add another line segment with a whole new call to `lineplot`, but that seems like overkill.  Can I do better?

(Using a built-in dataset for illustration):

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
sns.set_theme()

# Load an example dataset
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

mydata = tips[:10]  # Just to make it short

# Copy the first row to the end and plot it all:
mydata = pd.concat([mydata, mydata[:1]], ignore_index = True)
sns.lineplot(data=mydata, x="total_bill", y="tip", sort=False)
```

[image: open_path_missing_segment]

The current solution is to add this line (or, you know, not use seaborn):

```
sns.lineplot(data=mydata.iloc[[0,-1]], x="total_bill", y="tip", sort=False)
```

[image]

(Color just for emphasis)

How can we make a single `lineplot()` call build the entire closed loop?

Comment: Seaborn seems to group together rows with the same x-value. A trick could be to add some epsilon to the x-value (after the concat): `mydata.loc[0, ["total_bill"]] += 0.00001`

Comment: That led me to the right path, @JohanC... posted an answer that removes the grouping function.  That's a curious behavior indeed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@JohanC gave the comment that led to discovering the answer...

> Seaborn seems to group together rows with the same x-value.

Looking at the `seaborn.lineplot` [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html), the way to change this is with the `estimator` parameter (which, by defaults, aggregates to the mean y value for a given x):

```
sns.lineplot(data=mydata, x="total_bill", y="tip", sort=False, estimator=None)
```

[image]